# Taking an input as multiple elements instead of only 1

Tags: python-2.7, input

I'm trying to create a function that will take the input of the user to create a 3x4 matrix, then find the sum of each column individually. But I'm not sure how to set up the input so that I'll be given each number individually instead of a long string.

```
def testMatrixFunctions():
row0 = input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 0: ")
row1 = input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 1: ")
row2 = input("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row 2: ")
```

I could also use some help with adding the columns, but my biggest concern is the input at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str.split()` method:

```
>>> "1 2 3 4 5".split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

And then convert each string into an integer:

```
>>> map(int, "1 2 3 4 5".split())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [int(c) for c in "1 2 3 4 5".split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Good, but two problems. 1: Needs to accept decimals as well as integers. 2: when I try this, I get an error saying I can't split a tuple.

Comment: @Machinist'sGuardianArchangel: 1. Then use `float` instead of `int`. 2. Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Use split() function, which will split the input and you can 'eval' each element.

[eval(eachItem) for eachItem in inputList]

That will accept input regardless of the datatype.